# Kotlin's drawToBitmap() gives very small bitmap

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap

Kotlin's drawToBitmap() gives very small bitmap. How can i increase the size of the  bitmap without affecting quality?

my current code

```
fun getBitmapFromView(view: View): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    val bitmapCanvas = Canvas()

    bitmapCanvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
    bitmapCanvas.scale(4F, 4F);
    return bitmap
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `drawToBitmap` is as the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#(android.view.View).drawToBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap.Config)) says

> The resulting bitmap will be the same width and height as this view's current layout dimensions

so it will usually be the a maximum of the screen dimensions or smaller.

It's best to create a `view` specifically for drawing to a bitmap and then measure and layout it out for the size bitmap you want and then play with the bitmap scale as well.

An Example in Java https://stackoverflow.com/a/60582865/2373819

You can then create the bitmap as big as the view wants to be by measuring with `UNSPECIFIED` or as big as the you want it to be with `EXACTLY`

**Update: based on comment and updated question**

I think you missed the key points of the linked answer (and scale there was used to actually make the bitmap smaller)

1. You need to `measure`, `layout` and `draw` the view as if it was being displayed on a larger resolution screen, therefore you do not want to do this to `view` that you have already drawn to the screen.
2. So create a new `view` (either from xml or programmatically)
3. `measure` it to the size the `view` wants to be with `UNSPECIFIED`
4. Layout it out by calling layout
5. Create bitmap to the views size
6. Draw view to Bitmaps canvas instead of the screens canvas.

just ignore the `bitmapCanvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);` in the linked example.

Comment: good answer. upvoted. I tried what you said but I think I did it incorrectly. Please see my edit and please do inform me how to fix

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I read your steps and wrote code for it but it didn't work. would it be possible to provide working example code? I'll then accept your answer thanks :)

Comment: The answer has a linked example that is taken from a working app (just ignore the scaling) and you should be able to convert it from Java to kotlin.